# how to get text of push notification (Urban Airship)

Tags: push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I searched my questioin and didn't find the answer. So i'm using urban airship to push notifications and it is working fine. So now i want to make this: when user taps on notification to open the app i want to give him text of notification again in uialertview.
So where i can take the text of notification?
can i do this in this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

 UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
        appState = application.applicationState;
    }

    [[UAPush shared] handleNotification:userInfo applicationState:appState];
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can read the push notification that opened my app using `didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` - Here is my `didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    // TestFlight API
    TESTFLIGHT_CHECKPOINT(@"Receive Remote Notification");

    // Urban Airship
    [[UAPush shared] handleNotification:userInfo applicationState:application.applicationState];
    NSLog(@"userInfo: %@",userInfo);
    [UAInboxPushHandler handleNotification:userInfo];
}
```

When I launch my app from an aps notification I have this in the debug window:

```
2013-01-17 20:52:49:947 iFlightBag[8229:2311] -[AppDelegate_Shared application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:] [Line 2403] userInfo: {
    "_" = "l0-mgGElEeKbHAAbIbyL6A";
    aps =     {
        alert = "Manual: IOM update 2013-01-17T20:14:42-08:00";
        badge = 0;
    };
    operation = update;
    tab = manuals;
}
```